# Uncaught Error: Expected onClick listener to be a function, instead got type string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, listener, onclicklistener, event-listener

[This is the button where i called the handleClick function. I think the onClick event isn't working properly (only works if i equal it to `console.log('button clicked)` which logs the string to the console.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ftXQ.jpg)

[This is the `handleClick()` function which passes the value to the property of the component.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPKCQ.jpg)

I've no idea why it isn't working. Previously the onClick was firing up automatically but now it doesn't have that problem.

P.s: i tried an IIFE int the onCLick event and it still logs the message to the console but it doesn't seem to work with the `handleClick()`.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Any chance you could post the code itself and not an image..?

Comment: Please post this entire component if you could... it would be pretty helpful to figure out what `this.props.onClick()` is supposed to do...

Comment: @KarlReid Actually it's a really long code, so it wasn't possible to post the whole code.

Comment: @OneNeptune the onclick event calls a function in another component and updates its state (which needs the url as input).

It's just a simple pattern where this stateless component is updating a stateful component.

Comment: You're calling onClick on the props which likely includes a lot of stuff. Try putting a console.log or something in your constructor to find the path to that other component. Something like this.props.otherComponent.onClick is probably what you need.

Comment: @OneNeptune Sorry, I couldn't properly understand what you meant. can you please show me an example or send me a link or something which could help?? 

It would be really helpful. Thanks :)

Comment: So `this.props` will usually contain multiple objects, if your `onClick` inside the `handleClick` is supposed to reference a different object (which I'm assuming is a component, but we REALLY need you to post the code) then it'll likely be at something like `this.props.otherComponent`

Comment: @RishiKumar ultimately, we're all just guessing and can't form a proper answer until you post your code - not just truncated screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
handleClick:function(){
  return(this.props.onClick('app/src/wallpaperModule/3.jpeg'))
}
```

Comment: the function stil doesn't work. I put a `console.log()` inside the `handleClick()` (before return statement), but there's nothing on the console even after clicking on the button.

Comment: it seems like `onClick` isn't able to run the function.

Comment: @RishiKumar please post your code so I can better assist you. Also, `console.log()` won't put anything in the console if you don't supply an argument. Try putting `console.log(this.props)` inside your Component constructor.

Comment: `handleClick:function(){
    console.log('inside hc');
    return(this.props.onClick("app/src/wallpaperModule/3.jpeg"));
  },`

Comment: this is the `handleClick()` function.

Comment: @RishiKumar ALL the code for the relevant components please.